# Change owner of account depend on opportunity email

Tags: apex

Here I wrote the code for assign owner depend on contact email

this is my code:

```
List<user> users=[select id,email from user];
List<Account> accs[select id,name,ownerid,(select id,lastname,fastname from contacts) from account];
for(account a:accs){
   for(contact c:a.contacts){
       for(user u:users){
    if(c.email==u.email){
        a.ownerid=u.id;
    }
     }
   }
}
update accs;
```

but it is not good practice to write for loop with in the for loop...it can achieve using map..plz suggest me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some sample code, please update it as your requirements

```
Map<String, Id> email2UserId = new Map<String, Id>();
for(User u : [Select Id, Email from User])
{
    email2UserId.put(u.Email, u.Id);
}

Map<Id, Id> acctId2UserId = new Map<Id, Id>();
for(Contact c : [Select Id, AccountId, Email from Contact where Email in: email2UserId.values()])
{
    acctId2UserId.put(c.AccountId, email2UserId.get(c.Email));
}

List<Account> accts = [Select Id, OwnerId from Account where Id in: acctId2UserId.keyset()];
for(Account acct : accts)
{
    acct.OwnerId = acctId2UserId.get(acct.Id);
}

Update accts;
```